# SharePoint Calculated Columns Formula Issue

Tags: sharepoint, if-statement, calculated-columns

I have 9 columns that are set with a range of different numbers from 0-4 representing different statuses. In order for me to make my calculated column equal "Completed" i need to make sure all the 9 columns equal 0,3,4 or blank and nothing else.

Here's what i've come up with but it registers as invalid:

```
=IF(AND(OR([TF Task Status]=3,[TF Task Status]=4,[TF Task Status]=0,[TF Task Status]="")),AND(OR([TH Task Status]=3,[TH Task Status]=4,[TH Task Status]=0,[TH Task Status]="")),AND(OR([SUP Task Status]=3,[SUP Task Status]=0,[SUP Task Status]="")),AND(OR([EHSD Task Status]=3,[EHSD Task Status]=0,[EHSD Task Status]="")),AND(OR([EHSRV Task Status]=3,[EHSRV Task Status]=0,[EHSRV Task Status]="")),AND(OR([SM Task Status]=3,[SM Task Status]=0,[SM Task Status]="")),AND(OR([TL Task Status]=3,[TL Task Status]=0,[TL Task Status]="")),AND(OR([VP Task Status]=3,[VP Task Status]=0,[VP Task Status]=""))),"Completed","")
```

Is there an easy way of doing this? A way that works that isn't overly cumbersome?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `AND` operators inside your formula is not correct - you should simply chain the `OR` conditions as comma-delimited conditions within a single `AND` operator, as such:

```
=IF(AND(OR([TF Task Status]=3,[TF Task Status]=4,[TF Task Status]=0,[TF Task Status]=""),OR([TH Task Status]=3,[TH Task Status]=4,[TH Task Status]=0,[TH Task Status]=""),OR([SUP Task Status]=3,[SUP Task Status]=0,[SUP Task Status]=""),OR([EHSD Task Status]=3,[EHSD Task Status]=0,[EHSD Task Status]=""),OR([EHSRV Task Status]=3,[EHSRV Task Status]=0,[EHSRV Task Status]=""),OR([SM Task Status]=3,[SM Task Status]=0,[SM Task Status]=""),OR([TL Task Status]=3,[TL Task Status]=0,[TL Task Status]=""),OR([VP Task Status]=3,[VP Task Status]=0,[VP Task Status]="") ),"Completed","")
```

Tested & confirmed within a custom list in SharePoint 2010.